# Shorthand way of writing 人間?

Tags: kanji, handwriting

I'm reading a manga and this afterword bit is handwritten. I'm assuming that the circled character is meant to be 人間, but is that a valid way of writing it shorthand or is it a completely different compound?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43044/9831

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a common shorthand for 間.

Actually, 冂 with the vertical stroke is the shorthand for writing 門 as mentioned in [this Wikipedia article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%95%A5%E5%AD%97#%E5%85%B7%E4%BD%93%E4%BE%8B). As such any character with 門 radical can be abbreviated that way.

[image]

---

Related:

- [How often is 略字 (handwriting simplification) used?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/87136/45489)